# Why do you need to import React multiple times in parent and child components?

Tags: reactjs, import, webpack

If you have a parent component file that already imports `React`, why does any of its rendered children files also need to import React? Is it just a safety measure in case those children are ever rendered somewhere else where React has not been imported yet?

Answer (score 30):

In `nodejs` each file is a module, that has its own scope of variables. When you import variable into file (`React` for example) you add this variable to the module scope, but not to the global scope.

In case of `webpack` you can use [`providePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) to easily make `React` variable global:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  React: 'react' // ReactJS module name in node_modules folder
})
```

After that you are able to skip importing `React` variable in all of your modules. `Webpack` will do it itself where needed.

Comment: thanks! If a parent component file imports both React and a child component, wouldn't both be inside the parent's scope? Thus, wouldn't the child then get access to React?

Comment: But `nodejs` also has [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object to be said.

Comment: so it's just exporting the variables which are in module.exports, not the other files that were imported, correct?

Comment: actually, that doesn't answer why a parent that has React in its scope doesn't share it with a child that it has inside its scope as well. The child component is inside the parent component, which will then be exported with the child component and React. Before the parent component gets exported, it already has React and a child component inside it, so why wouldn't the child component just get access to the parent component's React?

Comment: the child component that is imported is in the same module scope as the React that is imported, isn't it?

Comment: This plugin is not working for me in 2019. It was last published 2 years ago. Anyone working with it with webpack 4?

Answer (score 30):

If you use `JSX` and `babel`, you have to import `React` in every file because `babel-preset-react` will transpile your `JSX` code into `React.createElement()` calls, so this code

```
const Foo = () => <h1>Test</h1>;
```

will be

```
var Foo = function Foo() {
  return React.createElement(
    "h1",
    null,
    "Test"
  );
};
```

DEMO: [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAYiEMC8MAUBKFA-GAeACwEZsAVAU2jwHpjsBuIA)

This is the reason why `React` should be accessible in the proper scope and one way to do it, is to import React in a file.

Comment: BUT why `babel` does not import `React` while transpiling and we should do it manually ?!!!

Comment: @dNitro BECAUSE it's just a tool to transform code. If you would like to have such feature in your project, you can always create a babel plugin for it or use something that already exists like https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-require

Answer (score 4):

The root of the question is one of dependency management -- how do I, the author, describe and obtain external dependencies I need in my "thing" (application/component/module) for it to do its job?

JavaScript benefits (or suffers) from having a global namespace in which dependencies can be injected. While this can often simplify dependency management in the short term (e.g. you can ignore it and expect everything you need to be available in the global namespace), it can often cause issues as an application grows and changes. For example, given an application with multiple contributors, one might decide to change a part of the application to no longer use a particular dependency and therefore remove it. If another part of the application needed it but that dependency wasn't formally declared anywhere, it could be easily missed.

To do dependency management well, each discrete "thing" should describe its dependencies independent of any other "thing" such that it can be safely used in any given context. This ensures that each "thing" has exactly what it needs no matter how it is used and what its "parent" (the code importing the "thing") has.

An alternative to this approach is dependency injection. In this model, the "thing" provides an interface for passing the dependencies into the "thing" from the consumer. There are flexibility and testability advantages to this which are out of scope of your question. :)

```
// export a function that expects the React and PropTypes
// dependencies to be injected as parameters and returns
// the component rather than importing the dependencies
// and exporting the component
export default (React, PropTypes) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
    render () {
      return (
        <div />
      );
    }
  };
};
```

All of that to say, it is somewhat a "safety measure" to have each "thing" import its own dependencies. It lets you safely refactor your code without the cognitive overhead of remembering what is providing those dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is to avoid unnecessary compiled a JavaScript code that you don't have to compile jsx. For example, you have a file that have a function to do adding, or whatever function that doesn't need to compile jsx, then you don't put **import React from 'react'** on the top of that file. This will save you compile time.