# Why do I need import React statement even if I don't use React explicitly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an React App, following is JavaScript code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = function(){
  return <div>Hi</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

And the HTML file is as following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAq06l5RUVfib62IYRQacLc-KAy0XIWAVs"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

The question I don't understand is that if I remove `import React from 'react'`, it will show error message like below.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

But I don't use React in my code explicitly anywhere, why would it show a message like this. Can anyone tell me what's going on under the hood?

**UPDATE:**
Not exactly the same question with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404730/why-do-you-need-to-import-react-multiple-times-in-parent-and-child-components), since what I have in my code is just an individual component, not involving any parent component.

Comment: @johnsam thanks, but we are not asking the a question in the same context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206646/do-we-need-to-import-react-or-just-component-proptypes-will-do I think this is also another question which was asked. Can you confirm ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using JSX (`<App />`) is just a syntatic sugar for `React.createElement()`.

So when your code is transpiled to pure javascript, references to `React` will appear there, so you need the import for  that.

So yes, you're using it, although you don't see it

See what is your code transpiled to [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgHIpUMBaAExLIG4AoZtCAOwGd4BBMMHAC8hAK4cMwTgAoAlAG9mcOJRiioHOAB5awAG4A-ABLAtAel2HmAX1bJ0WPADpKHWkijSt_QWYMAaOHo0URAkDhgnAEdRDwBPAGUkABskDGhpMid2CJRgDg8yWVlGIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

```
'use strict';

var _reactDom = require('react-dom');

var _reactDom2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reactDom);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var App = function App() {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    'Hi'
  );
};

_reactDom2.default.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: which means Babel have done the heavy lifting work for me under the hood??

Comment: well.. basically, yes

Comment: Out of curiosity, why couldn't the transpiler automatically insert the required imports? Are they trying to allow users to import React in an unusual way? Or substitute a different implementation? Preact?

Comment: this response is old, now some transpilers such as the one used by NextJs do inject automatically the required import